# How to deal with this ERROR (1049, "Unknown database '/users/ohyunjun/work/astral/mysql'")

Tags: database, django

In the Django `settings.py`, I set databases option this way

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysql'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'sp153426',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

And I executed this command

> python manage.py syncdb

But failed with this error

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 435, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database '/users/ohyunjun/work/astral/mysql'")
```

Comment: `name` is the database name. Not the absolute path.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`'NAME'` is the name of your database. With MySQL, you need to manually create your database too. Let's say, if you run:

```
$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

your configuration should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'sp153426',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I already have a database ( .sql) which I need to load? I don't wish to create a new empty database.

Comment: On some occasions, you should delete the DB and recreate it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with Django, PyMySQL and AWS RDS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man it just required that the database should already be created in MySQL.

Comment: Please consider updating your answer. If you read the code from the question's `settings.py` file you can see that the DB name is the full file system path. This is obviously the issue. If you want to expand into other reasons you would see a `1049` error please write a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I use docker to start mysql.

I changed the database name, then have same error.

After remove docker's volume cache, thing be ok!

```sh
docker volume --help
docker volume ls
docker volume  rm xx yy
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need  to create database in Mysql database with the name which you write in your settings.py in mysql connectivuty code
settings.py

`DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'name_of database', 'USER': 'root', 'PASSWORD': 'sp153426', 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'PORT': '3306', } }`

here name_of_database - is needed already in your database

create with sql query

```
           `CREATE DATABASE name_of Database;`
```