# Django error with connect mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

At first, I try to connect the MySQL in .py, it is successful.

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='admin',port=3306)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print ("Database version : %s " % data)
db.close()
```

But when I use in the Django, is wrong

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASEWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

----the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

----i add the "import pymysql"in "settings.py"

the error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'HelloWorld.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named pymysql
```

version:
mac
python 3.6
django:1.7.11

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using different virtual environments for your standalone test .py and your Django application; and pymysql is not installed in the Django virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

in your virtual enviroment install mysqlclient using pip:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

check your python compatibility version here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

and specify the version to install like this:

```
pip install mysqlclient==x.x.x
```

For python 2.7 you can use 1.3.4 and latest version 1.3.10

Comment: i used python 3.6 and  django:1.7.11

Comment: well. install that and tell me whats happened

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Use pip freeze to know what mysqlclient version u have installed. Then uninstall your mysqlclient using pip uninstall mysqlclient. And finally install the right version.

Comment: your comment reminds me . i use python3 manage.py.......it looks useful ...but new error is appears:django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'testdb'")
i m sure i already creat the database in mysql and the information is correctly.....

Comment: that error was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462007/how-to-deal-with-this-error-1049-unknown-database-users-ohyunjun-work-astra