# django - Connect an existing MySQL db to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a database that i would like to use for an app in my new Django project.
I tried adding it to the `setting.py` by doing the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Colta_create'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'toor123',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

I have installed `mysqlclient`, but i get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'colta_create'")
```

Comment: You need to add the host and port. If you're running it locally. `localhost` and `3306`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: And you're sure the database exists? No typo in the name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with this ERROR (1049, "Unknown database '/users/ohyunjun/work/astral/mysql'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462007/how-to-deal-with-this-error-1049-unknown-database-users-ohyunjun-work-astra)